# how to search for this kind of graph

Tags: angular, graph

i need to display graph based on the data. I need to show graph like this. Can anyone help me to find out this kind of graph.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1):

These graphs are used mostly to compare values between the segments or during one time period. One well-known example where you can see these kinds of graphs is the Stock exchange. You can find more details here at [Tableau Arrow Chart](http://www.vizzingdata.com/advanced-charting-arrow-charts-in-tableau/) and [Tableau Advance Charts](http://www.vizzingdata.com/category/tableau-tutorial/tableau-advanced-charts/).

**Update:**
The arrows in the graph are called **Key performance indicators (KPIs)**
also called **“strategic measures”** — are both actions and tools of measurement used to monitor the progress toward achieving these objectives.

Comment: Thanks for response, i am getting no access to this page

Comment: if there is any stackblitz example as such can u pls share me those links

Comment: I still see no problem while accessing the above-mentioned links. Hope below youtube videos are accessible to you and you can implement the logic explained in this video in your desired language.
1. [How to Display KPIs Next to Bars](https://youtu.be/OUTi12VtXpU)
2. [Combination of Bar Chart and Arrow key using Parameter](https://youtu.be/LljOLTiPVwA)
I would also like to know what language you are considering to implement the above graph feature.

Comment: is there any demo along with code for these? im in bad need of help

Comment: i need to do in angular, do we have any plugins fr this?